# Rollback a transaction in ejbs

Tags: java, jboss, ejb-3.0

I have a rest class which accepts a multipart request, saves a file in a particular location and calls an ejb service to save so hash in our database.

The flow is like below

Rest -> service -> dao

In my service class I am injecting the dao. Due to some reason the dao is not initialized and injected into the service class and I get a null pointer exception.

The file should be deleted in this case because ejbs have transaction management capabilities. But the file is not being deleted. 
Do I need to additionally enable transaction management somewhere in the container?

My rest class is not an ejb. Is it because my rest class is not an ejb, that is why the file is not being deleted?

BTW I am using jboss eap 6.1

Can anyone please help?

For simplicity I have written a new code with almost same thing my original code is doing

```
@Stateless
@Local
@TransactionManagement
public class ImportUpgradeServiceImpl implements ImportUpgradeService {

    @Inject
    private UpgradePackageDao upgradePackageDao;

    @Override
    public boolean savePackage() {

        File file = new File("d:\\ejbtest.log");

        try {
            file.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        upgradePackageDao.savePackageHash(null);

        return false;
    }

}
```

Below is my DAO

```
public class UpgradePackageDaoImpl implements UpgradePackageDao {

    @Override
    public void savePackageHash(String hash) {

        throw new RuntimeException("cannot save");
    }

}
```

I ran the ejb with @TransactionManagement and without @TransactionManagement. Both scenarios I can still see "ejbtest.log" file created in my D: drive

Comment: A small update. We are extracting the file in rest, passing it to service, service class is saving the file, dao is persisting the hash

Comment: To me atleast, Code speaks better than explanation

Comment: @Octopus Added a sample code. Can you please check once?

Comment: Do you have a bean.xml?

Comment: Yeah, I have it in under my ejb jar's META-INF folder

Comment: What does it have? Try adding `@Named("upgradePackageDao")` to `UpgradePackageDaoImpl` Class. Add a default constructor with `@inject`. This may help bean to look up by CDI

Comment: The question is regarding roll-backing the file i have saved in some directory. I don't understand what you are trying to tell me.

Okay, I will again try to reframe my question. Due to some reason injection failed or in some layer some exception happened. I want to rollback the file save operation I have done in the previous layer. Will ejb transaction management do that or not? If yes, how can I achieve the rollback

Comment: I'm sorry. I was lookin to solve the `NPE`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Transaction is not rolled back in ejb](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22446916/transaction-is-not-rolled-back-in-ejb)