# Transaction is not rolled back in ejb

Tags: java, transactions, ejb-3.0

I am not an ejb expert. I have a service class like below. I am saving a file in some location in my service class and calling a method in dao to save the file hash code. Due to some reasons some time I get an exception in my dao layer. Recently I observed the file which is saved from my service layer is not deleted when I get excxeptions.

```
@Stateless
@Local
@TransactionManagement
public class ImportUpgradeServiceImpl implements ImportUpgradeService {

    @Inject
    private UpgradePackageDao upgradePackageDao;

    @Override
    public boolean savePackage() {
        //For the sake of simplicity I simplified the code here
        File file = new File("d:\\ejbtest.log");

        try {
            file.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        upgradePackageDao.savePackageHash(null);

        return false;
    }

}
```

Below id my DAO

```
public class UpgradePackageDaoImpl implements UpgradePackageDao {

    @Override
    public void savePackageHash(String hash) {

        throw new RuntimeException("cannot save");
    }

}
```

Then I annotated my service class with @TransactionManagement. What am I missing? Or am I misunderstanding ejb transaction management? Is ejb transaction mamangement designed only for database transactions?

Comment: Can anyone please shed some light on this?

Comment: Can anyone please answer my question?

Comment: Take a look at the first two answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422603/how-to-manage-transaction-for-database-and-file-system-in-java-ee-environment)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interaction with the file system isn't recommended within EJB. Below is the excerpt from the [EJB Restrictions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/restrictions-142267.html) which explains it.

> **Why can't EJBs read and write files and directories in the filesystem?
>   And why can't they access file descriptors?**
>
> Enterprise beans aren't allowed to access files primarily because
>   files are not transactional resources. Allowing EJBs to access files
>   or directories in the filesystem, or to use file descriptors, would
>   compromise component distributability, and would be a security hazard.

As file isn't a transactional resource, rollback will have no effect on it.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. If you write your own FileSystemDataSource it would work out because it hides/handles the transaction.

Comment: @Markus Yes, with FileSystemDataSource rollback/commit operations can be done, but that will be altogether a different transaction & can't interrelate them with EJB transaction.